# imshow() not showing all the pixels without zooming in

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am plotting an array with `imshow`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
im = ax.imshow(b, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

It shows a few pixels.
[image]

If I zoom in more pixels show.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.xlim(1000, 1500)
plt.ylim(700, 1200)
im = ax.imshow(b, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I show all the pixels on the original zoomed out image?

[Here is the array I am trying to plot.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QyP50ItXXD4SdyDuUhbDJU32DSSo9Dds/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is a question of resolution. If you have more image pixels than you have physical pixels in the output (e.g. screen pixels), some of them necessarily get lost. Judging from the images you show, it seems that some pixels are more important to you than others, so maybe using a `plot` of non-zero pixels would be more useful here?

Comment: `interpolation='nearest'`: do you have more options? Your screen can only show *whole* pixels, so if a data point (which is *not* equal to a single pixel) is "smaller" than an actual, physical, measurable, addressable and quantifiable pixel on your current screen with the current zoom settings, what ought to be shown?

Comment: Thanks for the insight @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and @usr2564301. It works when I use a different `interpolation` (ex. gaussian).